# Cakephp 2 hash function to generate a new array

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Hi i do receive an array in this format :

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      22 => string 'One string' (length=20)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      8 => string 'Another string' (length=17)
```

How can i use cakephp hash to create another array usign 8 and 22 as indexes :

```
  array (size=2)
        22 => string 'One string' (length=20)
        8 => string 'Another string' (length=17)
```

I try  `hash::nest` but the result is :

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'One string' (length=17)
      'children' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      1 => string 'Another string' (length=20)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'One string' (length=17)
      'children' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      1 => string 'Another string' (length=20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with [Hash::merge](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::merge)

```
$formattedArray = Hash::merge($array[0], $array[1]);
```